# Tab bar/tab item disappears on two of tabs in my app

Tags: ios, tabs

In my storyboard app, I have a `UITabController`, which leads to a number of `UIViewController`.

Two of these primary `UIViewController` have a series of buttons which lead to secondary `UIViewController`.

Each of those secondary `UIViewController` displays html content, and they each have a button to go back to the primary `UIViewController` and a button to go back to the `UITabController`.

On the primary `UIViewController`, the tab bar displays fine with the various items. If I click a button to go to a secondary `UIViewController`, and then click the button to take me back to the primary `UIViewController`, I noticed that the `UITabBar` and items are not appearing.

Is there a setting that I need to change with regards to the tab bar to force it to display on the primary view when returning from the secondary view?
(PS ignore the website that shows in the screenshot of the secondary view, for some reason in the simulator it shows the website, but when I compile and run on an actual device it displays the correct html file that is hosted on the same site).

[image: Primary View Controller][image: Secondary View Controller][image: Primary View Controller after returning from Secondary View]

Comment: What code or segues are you using to go to the secondary controllers, and then back to the primary?

Comment: I'm using modal segues for both directions

Comment: Well that's your problem. Segues always instantiate new view controllers. Going back, you either need to dismiss in code or use an unwind segue.

Comment: Are you opening another view by Push animation or Present? And if its present then are you dismissing controller properly? I mean to say if you can check that you did not make first view as root view by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using modal segue then it is meaning present `UIViewController`.

Unlike push(show) navigation, present `UIViewController` can be said overlay it's `UIViewController` on top of it.

Let's say `viewController1` is one of `tabViewController` item and you are going to present `viewcontroller2`.

Then you are present `viewcontroller1` again on top of `viewController2`.

This is meaning at the bottom there's `viewController1` nested in `UITabController` and `viewController2` on top of it and another `viewController1` on top of it again.

That's `UIViewController` doesn't have tab items and tab bar.

So to go back, you'd rather to use dismiss `UIViewController` instead of present it again.